# Finding Scaled Distance on topojson

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have been evaluating different approaches to relate pixel space with distances (in real units) given a projection. I have found the following very helpful:

```
var actual_map_bounds = d3.geo.bounds(this_topojson);

    var radians = d3.geo.distance(actual_map_bounds[0], actual_map_bounds[1]);
    var earth_radius = 3959;  // miles
    var arc_length = earth_radius * radians;  // s = r * theta

    var projected_map_bounds = [
      this_projection(actual_map_bounds[0]),
      this_projection(actual_map_bounds[1])
    ];

    var projected_map_width = projected_map_bounds[1][0] - projected_map_bounds[0][0];
    var projected_map_height = projected_map_bounds[0][1] - projected_map_bounds[1][1];
    var projected_map_hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(
      (Math.pow(projected_map_width, 2)) + (Math.pow(projected_map_height, 2))
    );

    var pixels_per_mile = projected_map_hypotenuse / arc_length;
    var pixel_distance = pixels_per_mile * miles;
```

But my current application would benefit a lot by reducing the calculation steps needed. Are there any simpler or more 'elegant' solutions available to topojson developers?

Comment: No offense, but if this works, I haven't understood, what you are actually asking about ;-) Could you be more specific? What is your actual input and what output are you expecting? Can you describe in *words* what you are trying to do?

Comment: BTW, for those looking, this code snippet is from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/thomasthoren/6a543c4d804f35a240f9).  My question for the OP is: I'm guessing the calculation you really care about here is: `var pixel_distance = pixels_per_mile * miles;`?  So unless you are changing your projection or your topojson you can do the bulk of these calculations *only once*.

Comment: Yes, I'm after `pixel_distance`, and you're right, I only have to compute them once. However I'm using this for many html files, and while I do have copy/paste at my disposal, I would like to reduce lines not so much for computational efficiency, but for readability. Its not bad, but just needs so many lines that the intuition is almost lost by the time you get to `pixel_distance`. Also the longer a code is, the higher the propensity for user error is (especially if you're me ;)) So I thought because one of d3's specialties is relating data to pixel space there might be a better approach.

Comment: The inputs could be as per the link that mark provided, `function pixelLength(this_topojson, this_projection, miles)` My end goal is to use this pixel distance as a `.filter()` criterion. Like finding the distance between point A and a number of other points. Maybe `.filter(function(d) { return (d.data.get(pixel_length)) };)` I want to return only points that are within `pixel_distance` say 20 miles in pixels to A. I got lost in all the mixed spaces, so that's why I want to simplify the computation. If you know how to filter this way, I would accept that as an answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking and it doesn't really have anything to do with `d3` but more just JavaScript.  The question really is:

> How can I make this a reusable function that doesn't re-run the bulk of the calculations without resorting to global variables?

The answer is a closure:

```
function pixelLength(this_topojson, this_projection) {

    var actual_map_bounds = d3.geo.bounds(this_topojson);

    var radians = d3.geo.distance(actual_map_bounds[0], actual_map_bounds[1]);
    var earth_radius = 3959;  // miles
    var arc_length = earth_radius * radians;  // s = r * theta

    var projected_map_bounds = [
      this_projection(actual_map_bounds[0]),
      this_projection(actual_map_bounds[1])
    ];

    var projected_map_width = projected_map_bounds[1][0] - projected_map_bounds[0][0];
    var projected_map_height = projected_map_bounds[0][1] - projected_map_bounds[1][1];
    var projected_map_hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(
      (Math.pow(projected_map_width, 2)) + (Math.pow(projected_map_height, 2))
    );

    var pixels_per_mile = projected_map_hypotenuse / arc_length;

    return function(miles){
      var pixel_distance = pixels_per_mile * miles;
      return pixel_distance;
    }
  }
```

Now `pixelLength` will return a function that can be used to calculate pixel distance for the same topojson and projection over and over:

```
var pixelCalc = pixelLength(topojson.feature(data, data.objects['parishes']), projection4);

pixelCalc(1); // pixels for 1 mile
pixelCalc(100); // pixels for 100 miles
```

Here it is in action:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Map distance scales</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .parishes {
    fill: white;
    stroke: #777;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  .parish-border {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #353535;
    stroke-opacity: 0.4;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  .state-border {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #585858;
  }

  .distance-scale {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
  }

  .distance-scale-line {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    fill: #000;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var width = 960,
      height = 500;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var projection4 = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 31.2])
    .rotate([91.6, 0])  // Rotate CCW (looking down onto North Pole)
    .parallels([29, 33])
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale(6000);

  var map_path4 = d3.geo.path().pointRadius(2).projection(projection4);

  queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://jsonblob.com/api/e98bb5d0-df6f-11e6-90ab-c5f0718ee343")
    .await(ready);

  function pixelLength(this_topojson, this_projection) {

    var actual_map_bounds = d3.geo.bounds(this_topojson);

    var radians = d3.geo.distance(actual_map_bounds[0], actual_map_bounds[1]);
    var earth_radius = 3959;  // miles
    var arc_length = earth_radius * radians;  // s = r * theta

    var projected_map_bounds = [
      this_projection(actual_map_bounds[0]),
      this_projection(actual_map_bounds[1])
    ];

    var projected_map_width = projected_map_bounds[1][0] - projected_map_bounds[0][0];
    var projected_map_height = projected_map_bounds[0][1] - projected_map_bounds[1][1];
    var projected_map_hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(
      (Math.pow(projected_map_width, 2)) + (Math.pow(projected_map_height, 2))
    );

    var pixels_per_mile = projected_map_hypotenuse / arc_length;
    
    return function(miles){
      var pixel_distance = pixels_per_mile * miles;
      return pixel_distance;
    }
  }

  function ready(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var map4 = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "parishes")
      .attr("id", "map4");

    map4.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.parishes).features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", map_path4);

    map4.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(data, data.objects.parishes, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "parish-border")
      .attr("d", map_path4);

    map4.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(data, data.objects.parishes, function(a, b) { return a === b; }))
      .attr("class", "state-border")
      .attr("d", map_path4);

    // Distance scale
    // Line path generator
    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
      .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
      .interpolate("basis");

    // Scale4
     
    var pixelCalc = pixelLength(topojson.feature(data, data.objects['parishes']), projection4);

    var distance_scale4 = svg.selectAll("#distance-scale4")
        .data(d3.range(1, 100, 5))
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "distance-scale")
        .attr("id", "distance-scale4")
        .attr("transform", function(d,i){
          return "translate(20, " + (i * 20 + 40) + ")"
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return d; });

    distance_scale4.append('text')
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d){
        return d + " miles";
      });

    distance_scale4.append('path')
      .attr("class", "distance-scale-line")
      .attr("d", function(d, i) {
        var p = pixelCalc(d);
        var lineData = [
          {"x": 0, "y": 0},
          {"x": p, "y": 0}
        ];

        return line(lineData);
      });
  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDITS**

**Wait** all you want is the distance between points?  Ah, man, I misread that.  It's should just be:

```
// since earth is sphere
var radians = d3.geo.distance([p1.Longitude, p1.Latitude], [p2.Longitude, p2.Latitude]);
var numberMiles = radians * 3959; // radius of earth
```

Comment: It doesn't totally get to what I was after, but it might still work, it does simplify things enough. I guess I was wondering if there was a built in way rather than solving by a known variable, i.e. earth's radius, but this works fine after all. If you don't mind, I have a follow up question, how would I reference this with a `.filter()` to return only points that are within 100 miles of a given point `point_A` on the topojson?  `.filter(function(d) return { (projection([d.Longitude,d.Latitude]) < pixelcalc(100));})`??

Comment: @ArashHowaida, if you just want the miles between to long/lats, the [solution should be easy](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Paths.md#distance).  See edits above.

Comment: thank you for the great answer! so `geo.distance` is a built in function?

Comment: @ArashHowaida That's why I was asking in my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765941/finding-scaled-distance-on-topojson#comment70723584_41765941) what you are after! The entire calculations didn't make any sense to me. I think they are either wrong or only applicable under very special, small-scale conditions. Glad, that Mark's edit finally brought up the correct solution!